# How to implement "group-by" sampling in Hive?

Tags: hive

Given a Hive table:

```
create table mock
(user string,
 url string
);
```

How to sample a certain percentage of `url` (say 50%) or certain number of `url` for **each** `user`?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [built-in query](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Sampling) to extract samples from a table.

```
SELECT * FROM mock TABLESAMPLE(50 PERCENT)
```

Here is an alternative solution using `row_number()`. First number each rows for each user

```
with numbered as (
  SELECT user, url, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY user) as rn FROM mock
)
```

Then just either select the odd or even rows using `pmod` to get 50% sample

```
SELECT user, url FROM numbered where pmod(rn,2) = 0
```